# Inheritance between clr project dlls

Tags: .net, inheritance, dll, c++-cli, clr

I have an abstract base class which is written with c++/cli. This class is located in a project. And i have other projects which inherit the abtract base class. So, the structure is like the following.

Base Project:

```
public ref class Base abstract
{
  // implementation
  virtual CommonFunc();
};
public delegate void Foo();
```

Derived Project A:

```
public ref class A : public Base
{
  // implementation
};
```

Derived Project B:

```
public ref class B : public Base
{
  // implementation
};
```

And, so on. I can call both A and B classes on a C# project. No problem with that.

However, when i try to use Foo delegate of Base, it gets an error like following;

> Error : 'Foo' is an ambiguous reference between 'Foo' and 'Foo'

To get rid of this. I defined extern alias for references of A and B in the C# project. So, when i use like AliasA.Foo, it's ok. But, there exists two Foo's in two A and B dlls. That's a problem.

And at the end, when i try to develop some code like the following, the compiler doesn't know that the AliasBase.Base is base of A.

```
AliasBase.Base base = new A();
base.CommonFunc();
base = new B();
base.CommonFunc();
```

> Error : Cannot implicitly convert type 'A' to 'Base'

I hope I made myself clear. To summerize; i have three dlls. One of them is base's dll and the others are inteherited class's dlls. The inherited class's dlls contains their own base implementation inside. Is there a way of get rid of multiple implemtantatins of the base class?

Note: Yes, if i collect them into a project, there will be no problem. But, i'm requested to deliver seperated dlls for all derived items.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably code you put in a .h file and #included in the other source files.  So now there are multiple definitions of Base and Foo.  And B and C do not have the same Base class, a problem you did not run into yet but probably will.  Just don't use an .h file, the A and B projects need to use an assembly reference for Base.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I get rid of #include "Base.h" lines and add a reference to Base project to inheretec class's projects. But, it cannot recognize the Base class now. I tried to add #import "Base.dll", but it couldn't load the file. What's wrong?

Comment: Hard to guess of course.  Big changes, you definitely need Build > Rebuild to make IntelliSense smart enough again.  Beware of namespaces, something else we can't see.  You'll surely need to add some `using namespace` statements now if you didn't use any before.

Comment: Dear @HansPassant, I found the problem. The problem is due to i have a mixed type class which has a include to managed file. So, managed file's header is defining twice because of it. One is for the reference, one is for include. But, i cannot remove the header because of the mixed type class is not in the reference. To add a note: mixed type class is mixed type because of it has a interface class constructer parameter. I wrapped it with gcroot, it's ok but because of the interface's include statement, the interface class is declared twice. How can i solve this issue? Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Dear @HansPassant,
I removed the managed header file from unmanaged header and changed the parameter to LPVOID. Then reintepret_cast interface to LPVOID. It worked. But, it's not a good solution for performance issues. Soi i'll try to add native class's to reference.Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hans Passant suggested on comment, i got rid of header files and used only references,at the end inheritence worked. I had to set only one alias for base class on C# side and it has an inheritance relationship with parant classes. So, the following codes are working now.

```
AliasBase.Base base = new A();
base.CommonFunc();
base = new B();
base.CommonFunc();
```