# lpvoid to interface reference invalid cast exception

Tags: casting, c++-cli, clr

I have problems casting a class to LPVOID and than recasting it to interface class. Here is the simplified code:

```
public interface class IEventRaiser
{
   void fireAppDisconnect()
   // some other methods
}

interface class ISpecificEventRaiser : IEventRaiser
{
   // some specific methods
}

public ref class ManagedItem
{
   ManagedItem()
   {
      eventRaiser = gcnew EventRaiser();
      LPVOID lP = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(eventRaiser)).ToPointer();
      item = new UnmanagedItem(lP);
   }
   // some implementation
   ref class EventRaiser : public ISpecificEventRaiser
   {
      virtual void fireAppDisconnect();
      // other methods
   };

   EventRaiser^ eventRaiser;
   UnmanagedItem* item;
};

public class UnmanagedItem
{
   UnmanagedItem(LPVOID eventRaiser)
   {
      IEventRaiser^ r;
      IntPtr pointer(eventRaiser);
      handle = GCHandle::FromIntPtr(pointer);
      r = safe_cast<IEventRaiser^>(handle.Target); // InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'EventRaiser' to type 'IEventRaiser'.
   }
};
```

There should be no problem with casting to EventRaiser^ to IEventRaiser^, because i tried it before. Before trying to LPVOID conversations, it was working fine. But when i cast it into LPVOID and recast it to IEventRaiser, it throws InvalidCastException. How can i do the castings via LPVOID properly?

Comment: Dear @HansPassant,
It will live until the lifetime of the app and i'll call handle.free() on destructor. 
I tried to wrap the reference as IEventRaiser but, it throws the same exception. Like following;

ISpecificEventRaiser^  sEventRaiser = (ISpecificEventRaiser^)eventRaiser;
lp = reinterpret_cast<LPVOID>(GCHandle::ToIntPtr(GCHandle::Alloc(safe_cast<IEventRaiser^>(sEventRaiser ))).ToPointer();

Comment: Banging this code snippet into shape so it can compile is hard work.  Works fine either way when I try it, the cast is not the problem.  The probable mistake is that you have more than one definition of the interface type.  Which tends to happen when you declared it in a .h file and #included it in source files that belong to two different projects.  Type identity in .NET is not just defined by the namespace and identifier name, it also includes the full name of the assembly it lives in.  Use an assembly reference instead so there is only one definition of the interface.

Comment: Come to think of it, you already had this problem before.  You made the exact same mistake in your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47683677/17034).

Comment: Dear @HansPassant, i removed the .h files after my last question. So, interface class should not be defined twice. But, yes. It seems that it's an assembly problem. I printed the assebly name of the IEventRaiser handle and it was inherited assembly's name! But i cannot understand that how can it possible. On inherited project, there is only one header file to base project and it's for only native class's header file. And that header file does'nt inlude any of managed type headers. So, the interface class shouln't be included by native include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason to have a LPVOID pointer to my unmanaged class was to get rid of duplicate header imports. So, although i pay attention to included header files, IEventRaiser's header file was imported to inhereted project in some way. So, as Hans Passant indicated on comments, it causes a cast problem because of different assembly names. What i did to solve the problem is adding #ifdef statements to base project's IEventRaiser header file includes. Like the following:

```
#ifdef BASE_DLL 
#include "IEventRaiser.h"
#endif
```

Then, i added to "BASE_DLL" to preprocessor definitions. It guarantees that the event raiser header will be included once. The other alternative was using forward declarations for not to add "IEventRaiser.h" header file to unmanaged file header. It's also tried and working.